# How to take the value of a variable inside the curly braces?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I need the value of `that.assigned` outside the forEach but it would result with `undefined` if I ever use it as `console.log(that.assigned)` which is an array

```
assignedDoctors.then(function(doc){
  let i = 0;
  doc.forEach(function(md){
    tmpMDs.push(md.data());
    tmpMDs[i].key = md.id;
    // tmpMDs.push(md.data().push());
    i++;
  });
  that.assigned = tmpMDs;
}).catch(function(e){
  console.log(e);
});

console.log(that.assigned)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using ES 2017, then you can do it

```
(async function(){

that.assigned = await assignedDoctors.then(function(doc){
  let i = 0;
  doc.forEach(function(md){
    tmpMDs.push(md.data());
    tmpMDs[i].key = md.id;
    // tmpMDs.push(md.data().push());
    i++;
  });

  return tmpMDs;
});

})()
```

Otherwise, no way to use the callback.

Comment: I can't use the that.assigned outside async

Comment: No, you can't. This way javascript working. You can call it dis-advantage or beauty of javascript.

Comment: Oh okay got it. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

assignedDoctors.then is a promise function and you can not access value of that variable before calling the promise function.